# Pass multiple commands to started batch file from batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
    set consoleName="hello"
    set batch=echo foo
    start "%consoleName%" /max %batch% cmd.exe
```

This does works, output:
`foo` .
However, doing anything longer than one command does not work:

```
    set consoleName="hello"
    set batch=(
echo %itchy%
if %itchy% lss 50 (echo foo)
else
(echo bar)
)
echo hi
    start "%consoleName%" /max %batch% cmd.exe
```

Output:
`System cannot open file (.`
So far all of thoses don't work:

```
   set consoleName="hello"
    set batch=echo foo , echo bar
    set batch2= echo foo ^& echo bar
    start "%consoleName%" /max %batch% cmd.exe
    start "ex2" %batch%%batch% cmd.exe
    start "ex3" %batch2% cmd.exe
```

Outputs result in:
hello: `foo cmd.exe`
ex2  : `fooecho foo cmd.exe` (Inside command prompt:)

```
barecho foo
bar cmd.exe
```

ex3 : `foo cmd.exe`

I cannot use `clone` or `call`, I must use `start`.

Comment: Type `set batch` and look what you have actually assigned to variable `batch`. Anyway, your `if` syntax is wrong (see `if /?`). Nevertheless, you should try to explain what you actually want to achieve rather than just posting a few code fragments...

Comment: I would suggest you begin with `cmd /?` and `start /?`. But be aware that you cannot pass a series of individual commands on multiple lines within a parenthesised block as an argument to cmd.exe like this, even if `%itchy%` was defined somewhere! You may get lucky with concateneation, and may also be fortunate enough to create a multiline variable, but passing it as an argument and it being received as you need it, could be a complex issue.

Comment: you are looking for [Batch macros with parameters](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2518)